# How to force use of indices in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

How could we make MongoDB report errors for queries that don't use indices?

We end up creating indices for every query anyway so it would be great if MongoDB would report missing indices for us. Also it would be convenient to be able to configure the restriction on a connection basis. This way indices wouldn't come into our way when working from MongoDB shell.

Comment: notablescan is not quite what your looking for here and there is no exact functionality, since in DBs it is actually quite common to have unindexed queries at times. If you really want this then you will need to do in the application

Comment: We are working with quite large datasets, so all queries without indices get caught with timeouts in logs time to time. Google Datastore actually use approach of index-only queries: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes

Comment: Hmm, actually if what your looking for are queries that don't use an index at all in theory notablescan option should work

Comment: @Sammaye maybe you should post that as an answer as [notablescan](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan) appears to be a possible solution here. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292140/partial-answer-in-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notablescan ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan ) option for the MongoDB binary (mongod.exe or mongod depending on your OS) allows you to stop any query, with an emitted log error, which does not use an index at all.

This option will not stop inefficient queries though so that part will still need to be discovered manually by you.

Comment: It looks like what we need. However, `notablescan` per connection is not yet supported what makes the feature much less useable: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1143